# accessing prototype property without using "new" to instantiate function object

Tags: javascript

In Crockford's book "Good Parts", he mentions to avoid using "new" because it is an anti-pattern, since the language is prototypal and not classical. However, using his advice, I am unable to use the prototype property. I tried several different things:

// In the below example, we are unable to access the prototype property, because while parent is initialized with a function object, which has access to prototype property, when parent is executed, we return an object literal, which does not have access to that property. The error we get below is "TypeError: p.info is not a function". That happens because info is undefined for p, since p is an object literal. It is parent that has the prototype property.

```
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";
    var that = {};

    that.name = function(){
            return name;
    }

    that.age = function(){
        return age;
    }
    return that;
}

parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info());
```

// Here we suffer from the same problem above:

```
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";

    return {
        name: function(){
            return name;
        },
        age: function(){
            return age;
        }
    }
}

parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info());
```

// this won't work either because "p" will be undefined since the return value of the function is undefined. Besides, "this" would refer to the global object, which is window in browsers.

```
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";

    this.name = function(){
        return name;
    }
    this.age = function(){
        return age;
    }
}

parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info());
```

// But using the "new" keyword to construct the object allows us to access the prototype. That must mean that the return value of Parent is a function and not a regular object. According to Stoyan Stefanov in his book "Javascript Patterns", when using the new keyword, under the covers a blank object is created which inherits from Parent's (the function) prototype: Object.create(Person.prototype). And then all references of "this" is attached to that object and it is returned.

```
var Parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";

    this.name = function(){
        return name;
    }
    this.age = function(){
        return age;
    }
}

Parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = new Parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info());
```

// Unfortunately, I cannot simulate this. I get the error: "TypeError: this.prototype is not an object or null". Obviously, at the point of use, "this" is not parent yet.

```
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";
    var that = Object.create(this.prototype);

    that.name = function(){
        return name;
    }
    that.age = function(){
        return age;
    }

    return that;
}

parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info())
```

So when Crockford says avoid using "new", how are we supposed to add properties to prototype?

Comment: you can use Object.create() or the newer setPrototypeOf(), or just extend().

Comment: You're misusing `this`.

Comment: @dandavis Object.create() was introduced with ES5. His book was around before that when he encouraged avoiding "new". So I would like a solution that does not involve ES5, if such solution even exists.

Comment: @JohnMerlino: i think doug called it begat() back in the day, but it's basically the same thing. Most  Object.create polyfills look like Dougs old object maker.http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Pre-ES5 I don't think you can completely avoid `new`, other than using `__proto__`. `Object.create` is the way to go.

Comment: i'm pretty sure Doug meant "don't use new all the time in your program code", not "don't ever use it at all".

Comment: DC's opinion on constructor functions is invalid in my opinion. He shows some faulty code and then blames the language. A polyfil for Object.create has been around for a long time. Like google closure inherits for example. They use Object.create for the prototype part of inheritance, not to avoid new altogether

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Object.create()` function you can do it like this:

```
// base, its prototype will be used to create a new parent
function Parent(name, age) {
    this.name = name || '';
    this.age = age || '';
};

// factory to create a new parent
function createParent(name, age) {
    var proto = Parent.prototype;
    var properties = {
        name: {writable: true, configurable: true, value: name || ''},
        age: {writable: true, configurable: true, value: age || ''}
    };
    var parent = Object.create(proto, properties);
    return parent;
}

// augment the Parent's prototype
Parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name + " age: " + this.age;  
}

// Create a new Parent
var p = createParent("John",25);

// Test
console.log("name: " + p.name + " age: " + p.age + " info: " + p.info());
```

You could check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more options/variations on how to use the `Object.create()` function.

You can achieve similar functionality with different approaches depending on your needs. A simple example:

```
var parentBase = {};
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";
    var that = parentBase;

    that.name = function(){
            return name;
    }

    that.age = function(){
        return age;
    }
    return that;
}

parentBase.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name() + " age: " + this.age();  
}

var p = parent("John",25);
console.log("name: " + p.name() + " age: " + p.age() + " info: " + p.info());
```

You better use `Object.create`, because it is in the ECMAS 5 and offers you more options, flexibility and functionality that you do not have to implement by yourself. Object.create implements the pattern described by Douglas Crockford. If the platform doesnt's support it then you could make your custom implementation as Crockford suggested [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

You can use the `Object.beget` similar with the `Object.create` as i described above. You could try it:

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {

     Object.beget = function (o) {

         var F = function () {};

         F.prototype = o;

         return new F();
     };
}

// base, its prototype will be used to create a new parent
function Parent(name, age) {
    this.name = name || '';
    this.age = age || '';
};

// factory to create a new parent
function createParent(name, age) {
    var proto = Parent.prototype;
    var parent = Object.beget(proto);
    parent.name = name || '';
    parent.age = age || '';
    return parent;
}

// augment the Parent's prototype
Parent.prototype.info = function(){
    return "name: " + this.name + " age: " + this.age;  
}

// Create a new Parent
var p = createParent("John",25);

// Test
console.log("name: " + p.name + " age: " + p.age + " info: " + p.info());
```

Comment: I tried his Object.beget, but still can't figure out how to attach properties to prototype even when using his Object.beget. This returns an error in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/77o57b1p/1/

Comment: I edited my answer to include a working example with Object.beget().

Comment: @JohnMerlino `Object.beget` accepts a prototype object and returns a newly-created object whose prototype chain begins with that passed-in object (i.e., `Object.beget(p)` returns an object `obj` for which `obj.__proto__ == p`). In your fiddle, you're passing in the return value of `parent`, but the result returned from `parent("John",25)` is just a plain object and has no relation to the prototype stored in `parent.prototype`. You need to do `Object.beget(person.prototype)` and set instance properties on that object returned from `Object.beget`.

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

```
var parent = function(name, age){
    var name = name || "";
    var age = age || "";
    // add `info` as `var`
    var that = {}, info;

    // change method to function expression
    that.name = (function(){
            return name;
    }())
    // change method to function expression
    that.age = (function(){
        return age;
    }())
    return that;
// add `|| {}` , for accessing `parent.info`
} || {};

// add param `that`  to `parent.info` function
parent.info = function(that){
    return "name: " + that.name + " age: " + that.age;  
};

var p = parent("John",25); 
console.log("name: " + p.name + " age: " + p.age + " info: " + parent.info(p));

// var results = document.createElement("div");

// results.innerHTML = parent.info(p);

// document.body.appendChild(results);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/v0tdtk80/